# How to display list of previous copies/kills (`M-w` or `C-w`)?

Tags: kill-ring

`C-n C-y` retrieves the n-last call to `C-w`, I think. Is there a way to show all that were saved?

Comment: See [Browse Kill-Ring](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of the `kill-ring` variable e.g. with C-h v kill-ring RET, or perhaps better, evaluate it in the `*scratch*` buffer with `kill-ring C-j`. The doc string of the variable says:

> List of killed text sequences.
>
> Since the kill ring is supposed to interact nicely with cut-and-paste
> facilities offered by window systems, use of this variable should
> interact nicely with `interprogram-cut-function` and
> `interprogram-paste-function`.  The functions `kill-new`,
> `kill-append`, and `current-kill` are supposed to implement this
> interaction; you may want to use them instead of manipulating the kill
> ring directly.

See also [the kill ring section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Kill-Ring.html#The-Kill-Ring) in the Emacs Lisp manual.

Answer (score 1):

The command `counsel-yank-pop` which is part of [the swiper package](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), gives you an interactive way to browse and insert elements from you kill ring.

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you want is provided by one of theses packages :

- [Popup-killring](https://github.com/waymondo/popup-kill-ring)  - Browse kill-ring with popup menu.
- [Browse-kill-ring](https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring) - Visually navigate kill-ring.

Spacemacs uses `consel-yank-pop` acessible with `SPC-r-y` (command already cited by @Heikki) provided by swipper. So you can also look at it.